# Cursor window allocation of 2048 kb failed appears very often

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have such code:

```
public int getExpRequirementsByLvl(int lvl) {
    int expRequired = 0;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor res = db.rawQuery("select * from levels where lvl=" + lvl + "", null);

    if (res.moveToNext()) {
        expRequired = Integer.parseInt(res.getString(1));
    }
    res.close();
    return expRequired;
}
```

`

and my calls look like this

```
if (((Gra) gs.getContext()).expOnline + 5 >=
                dbHelper.getExpRequirementsByLvl(((Gra) gs.getContext()).levelOnline + 1)
                        + dbHelper.getExpRequirementsByLvl(((Gra) gs.getContext()).levelOnline)     // up to 3lv
                        + dbHelper.getExpRequirementsByLvl(((Gra) gs.getContext()).levelOnline - 1)     // up to 4lv
                        + dbHelper.getExpRequirementsByLvl(((Gra) gs.getContext()).levelOnline - 2)  // up to 5lv
                        + dbHelper.getExpRequirementsByLvl(((Gra) gs.getContext()).levelOnline - 3)     // up to 6lv
                        + dbHelper.getExpRequirementsByLvl(((Gra) gs.getContext()).levelOnline - 4)     // up to 7lv
                        + dbHelper.getExpRequirementsByLvl(((Gra) gs.getContext()).levelOnline - 5) // up to 8lv
                        + dbHelper.getExpRequirementsByLvl(((Gra) gs.getContext()).levelOnline - 6)     // up to 9lv
                        + dbHelper.getExpRequirementsByLvl(((Gra) gs.getContext()).levelOnline - 7))    // up to 10lv
```

and this `getExpRequirementsByLvl()` is also called in handler.postDelayed() every second.

Why do I have `Cursor window allocation of 2048 kb failed.` error very often? How to fix this?